# AMD APP SDK v2.9 compiler bug

Tags: c++, c, opencl, gpu, amd-processor

I'm trying to build a simple program in OpenCL to calculate the value of pi using a Monte Carlo method, I'm using AMD's APP SDK on Intel CPU and AMD GPU,
this is the kernel source:

```
#define RAND_MAX 4294967295


float rand(uint *seed)
{
        *seed = *seed * 1103515245 + 12345;
        float res= *seed % ( RAND_MAX + 1);
        res/=RAND_MAX;
        return res;
}

__kernel
void pi(__global uint *seed, __global uint *res)
{
    int idx = get_global_id(0);
    uint loc_seed= seed[0] + idx;

    res[idx]=0;
    float x,y;
    uint i;
    for(i=0; i<100000; i++)
    {
        x=rand(&loc_seed);
        y=rand(&loc_seed);
        if( (x*x+y*y)>1 )
        {
            res[idx] += 1;
        }
    }

}
```

which does not compile, giving the following output, immediately when calling clBuildProgram causing the whole process to crash:

```
LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: 0x15b01a0: i64 = setcc 0x15aed90, 0x15b02a0, 0x15b2b80 [ORD=16] [ID=34]
  0x15aed90: i32 = add 0x15afda0, 0x15af6a0 [ORD=14] [ID=31]
    0x15afda0: i32 = mul 0x15af4a0, 0x15afba0 [ORD=13] [ID=28]
      0x15af4a0: i32 = add 0x15afaa0, 0x15af6a0 [ORD=9] [ID=26]
        0x15afaa0: i32 = mul 0x15aeb90, 0x15afba0 [ORD=8] [ID=25]
          0x15aeb90: i32,ch = CopyFromReg 0x1660540, 0x15ae890 [ORD=8] [ID=24]
            0x15ae890: i32 = Register %vreg2 [ORD=8] [ID=1]
          0x15afba0: i32 = Constant<1103515245> [ORD=8] [ID=2]
        0x15af6a0: i32 = Constant<12345> [ORD=9] [ID=3]
      0x15afba0: i32 = Constant<1103515245> [ORD=8] [ID=2]
    0x15af6a0: i32 = Constant<12345> [ORD=9] [ID=3]
  0x15b02a0: i32 = Constant<0> [ORD=16] [ID=10]
```

What's that? I'm sure the problem is somewhere in the kernel source because switching to another kernel file everithing runs just fine..

Thanks in advance

EDIT: it seems the problem lies in the number 4294967295, which is the largest unsigned int with 32 bits, but the compiler, for some reason, seems not to like it..

Comment: Have you checked the compiler log with `clGetProgramBuildInfo`?

Comment: Yes but it's useless because the program crashes before reaching that line, as I wrote it crashes immediately after the call to clBuildProgram..

Comment: Well it is not supposed to crash. You should send a bug report to your compiler vendor. OpenCL is quite new, so compilers have still a few bugs.

Comment: Try putting "U" at the end of the constant.. else maybe `(uint)-1`. It certainly is a compiler bug, but perhaps you can work around it for the time being.

Comment: @Thomas (uint)-1 works, good trick!